# example using dep_prev() in R Markdown?

Tags: r, caching, markdown, knitr

I'm looking for an example .Rmd that uses dep_prev() to specify that all later chunks depend on previous chunks. The documentation says:

"This function can be used to build dependencies among chunks so that all later chunks depend on previous chunks, i.e. whenever the cache of a previous chunk is updated, the cache of all its later chunks will be updated."

But the documentation does not specify how/where to call the function. Can you share an example?

Thanks!

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/knitr/versions/1.21/topics/dep_prev

Comment: thanks, @user2554330 ! do you have an example of using dep_prev()?

Comment: I don't think that is correct, I think it is only supposed to be called once? https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/285 "`dep_prev` is a function to be called in your first chunk; it is not supposed to be assigned to the chunk option `dependson`. Just write `dep_prev()` in your first chunk, and you are all set." is that correct? it would really help if the documentation were clear about this!

Comment: You're probably right, I've deleted the incorrect comment.